# Как лучше распарсить и группировать конфиг-файл на PHP?

Tags: php

Есть конфиг-файл, структура очень не удобная:

> [/deployment/test_host/CISCO_2]
>
> AdminInterface= ClassName=com.Process Description= 2016-11-01 ABS-222
>   Link=/deployment/test_host/CISCO_1
>   MBeanServerConnection=service:jmx:rmi://10.0.0.0/jndi/rmi://0.0.0.0/jmxconnector
>   QueryInterface=
>   SecureMBeanServerConnection=service:jmx:rmi://0.0.0.0.202/jndi/rmi://0.0.0.0:39189/jmxconnector
>
> [/deployment/test_host/CISCO_2/Aggregator]
>
> FileNameTemplate='%scheme/CISCO_'yyyyMMddHHmmss'*%FileName*%_%fileseq'
>
> [/deployment/test_host/CISCO_2/Aggregator/00]
>
> [/deployment/test_host/CISCO_2/Properties]
>
> MAXRESTARTTIMES=100000000 PROCESSARGS=-l 4 STARTUPMODE=Automatic
>
> [/deployment/test_host/CISCO_3]
>
> AdminInterface= ClassName=com.Process Description= 2016-11-01 ABS-222
>   Link=/deployment/test_host/CISCO_1
>   MBeanServerConnection=service:jmx:rmi://10.0.0.0/jndi/rmi://0.0.0.0/jmxconnector
>   QueryInterface=
>   SecureMBeanServerConnection=service:jmx:rmi://0.0.0.0.202/jndi/rmi://0.0.0.0:39189/jmxconnector
>
> [/deployment/test_host/CISCO_3/Aggregator]
>
> FileNameTemplate='%scheme/CISCO3_'yyyyMMddHHmmss'*%FileName*%_%fileseq'

Нужно из него вытаскивать все, что находится внутри конкретной ветки, например /deployment/test_host/CISCO_2 - включая то, начинается с /deployment/test_host/CISCO_2 и до нового агента [/deployment/test_host/CISCO_3]

Пока не понимаю как лучше это делать. Если только по имени агента фильтровать, тогда как вытащить еще и те строки, которые идут между путей-имен агентов (например FileNameTemplate...)

Comment: А этот конфиг вообще рабочий? Я к тому что у него очень странный формат в плане деллимитеров. Свойства разделяются переносом строки? Потому что складывается впечатление что у свойства `AdminInterface` значение, это набор свойство `ClassName`, `Description` но тут же врывается `ABS-222` оно относится к дескрипшену?

Comment: Конфиг рабочий. 
Разделяется да переносом строки видимо, сейчас просмотрел весь конфиг. 

Конфигурация конкретно агента находится между первым [/deployment/test_host/CISCO_2] и первым следующего агента [/deployment/test_host/CISCO_3/Aggregator]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Остается лишь отфильровать ключи массива по нужному вам префиксу

```
$lines = explode("\n", $configText);
$params = [];
$currentKey = null;

foreach ($lines as $row) {
    if (empty($row)) {
        continue;
    } elseif (preg_match('/^\s*\[(.*?)\]\s*$/', $row, $matches)) {
        $currentKey = trim($matches[1]);
        $params[$currentKey] = [];
    } elseif (preg_match_all('/(\w+)\=/', $row, $matches)) {
        $values = preg_split('/(\w+)\=/', $row);
        unset($values[0]);
        $values = array_map('trim', $values);
        $params[$currentKey] = array_combine($matches[1], $values);
    } else {
        throw new Exception('Unexpected scenario');
    }
}

print_r($params);
```

Ну а так можно обработать ключи представляемые как папки

```
$tree = [];

foreach ($params as $key => $values) {
    $arr = &$tree;
    $keys = explode('/', $key);
    unset($keys[0]);

    foreach ($keys as $key) {
        $arr = &$arr[$key];
    }

    $arr = $values;
}

print_r($tree);
```